# OSError:[Errno 22] with open() trying to use Exifread

Tags: python, exif

Trying to extract exif data from one image.
I am not a developer - I got this code from a web example.
Very much learning.

```
def process_img(path):
    f = open('C:\\Users\\evansg\\Desktop\\Photos_for_fun\\PestMonitoring_BTT003_20200527_RCNX1446.jpg/', 'rb')
    tags = exifread.process_file(f)
    info = {
        'Image DateTime': tags.get('Image DateTime', '0'),
        'GPS GPSLatitudeRef': tags.get('GPS GPSLatitudeRef', '0'),
        'GPS GPSLatitude': tags.get('GPS GPSLatitude', '0'),
        'GPS GPSLongitudeRef': tags.get('GPS GPSLongitudeRef', '0'),
        'GPS GPSLongitude': tags.get('GPS GPSLongitude', '0')
    }
    return info

info = process_img('PestMonitoring_BTT021_20200414_RCNX3611.jpg')
print(info)
```

Error is:

---

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-20569c66d6b9> in <module>
      8     return info
      9 
---> 10 info = process_img('PestMonitoring_BTT003_20200527_RCNX1446.jpg')
     11 print(info)

<ipython-input-6-20569c66d6b9> in process_img(path)
      1 def process_img(path):
----> 2     f = open("C:\\Users\\evansg\\Desktop\\Photos_for_fun\\PestMonitoring_BTT003_20200527_RCNX1446.jpg/", 'rb')
      3     tags = exifread.process_file(f)
      4     info = {
      5         'Image DateTime': tags.get('Image DateTime', '0'),

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\evansg\\Desktop\\Photos_for_fun\\PestMonitoring_BTT003_20200527_RCNX1446.jpg/'
```

However:

```
 entries = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\evansg\\Desktop\\Photos_for_fun/')
for entry in entries:
    print(entry)
```

Returns a list that includes desired file.
example:

```
IMG_0001.JPG
IMG_0251.JPG
IMG_0285.JPG
PestMonitoring_BRT011_20200204_IMG_0124.jpg
PestMonitoring_BRT011_20200329_IMG_0410.jpg
PestMonitoring_BRT011_20200406_IMG_0685.jpg
PestMonitoring_BRT012_20200119_IMG_0031.jpg
PestMonitoring_BRT014_20200221_IMG_0297.jpg
PestMonitoring_BRT014_20200312_IMG_0401.jpg
PestMonitoring_BRT015_20190901_IMG_1340.jpg
PestMonitoring_BRT015_20190929_IMG_8585.jpg
PestMonitoring_BRT016_20190817_IMG_0075.jpg
```

Further, I would like to expand this to include multiple folders. Advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

removed the / escape
file was in same folder was easier file name to manage.

```
def process_img(path):
    f = open('C:\\Users\\evansg\\Desktop\\Photos_for_fun\\IMG_0001.JPG', 'rb')
    tags = exifread.process_file(f)
    info = {
        'Image DateTime': tags.get('Image DateTime', '0'),
        
    }
    return info

info = process_img('IMG_0001.JPG')
print(info)
```

Result:

```
   [![{'Image DateTime': (0x0132) ASCII=2020:03:27 17:23:42 @ 154}][1]][1]
```